# Why does an <error-type> appears when switching from a template class?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, binary-search-tree

I implemented the following a Binary Search Tree using a template class:

```
#ifndef ROSTER_
#define ROSTER_

#include "BinaryNode.hpp"
#include "Visitor.hpp"
#include "Student.hpp"
#include "Printer.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Roster
{
public:
    Roster(); // Constructor
    Roster(const Roster<T>& tree); //Copy constructor
    ~Roster(); // Destructor
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int getHeight() const;
    int getNumberOfNodes() const;
    void add(const T& new_item);
    void add(const std::vector<T>& new_items);
    void remove(const T& target);
    void display();
    T find(const T& item);
    void clear();

    void inorderTraverse(Visitor<T>& visit) const;

    Roster& operator= (const Roster<T>& rhs);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> root_ptr_;
    std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> copyTree(const std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> old_tree_root_ptr) const;
    void destroyTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr);
    int getHeightHelper(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr) const;
    auto placeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr, std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> new_node_ptr);
    auto removeValue(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr, const T target);
    auto removeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> node_ptr);
    auto removeLeftmostNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> nodePtr, T& inorderSuccessor);
    void inorder(Visitor<T>& visit, std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> tree_ptr) const;
    //Operator overloading for students objects
    friend bool operator <(const Student& a, const Student& b);
    friend bool operator >(const Student& a, const Student& b);
    friend bool operator ==(const Student& a, const Student& b);
};
#include "Roster.cpp"
#endif
```

In this case I want to implement the same class but only using object of type Student. The implementation works when declaring as `Roster<Student> my_student;`

However when I try implementing the same code but instead of a template class is a class that only takes objects of type student therefore removing the template and specifying each function the data type for the BinaryNode<> I get an error time on two specific functions:

```
auto removeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> node_ptr);
auto removeLeftmostNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> nodePtr, Student& inorderSuccessor);
```

I get an "declaration is incompatible with "" Message:

```
auto Roster::removeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> node_ptr)
{

}
```

To see the full implementation of the .cpp for Roster.hpp for template class:

```
#include "Roster.hpp"

//Constructor
template<class T>
Roster<T>::Roster()
{
    root_ptr_ = nullptr;
}

//Copy Constructor
template<class T>
Roster<T>::Roster(const Roster& tree)
{
    root_ptr_ = copyTree(tree.root_ptr_);
}

//Destructor
template<class T>
Roster<T>::~Roster()
{
    destroyTree(root_ptr_);
}

//Check if empty
template<class T>
bool Roster<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return root_ptr_ == nullptr;
}

//Clear
template<class T>
void Roster<T>::clear()
{
    destroyTree(root_ptr_);
}

//Get height
template<class T>
int Roster<T>::getHeight() const
{
    return getHeightHelper(root_ptr_);
}

//Add
template<class T>
void Roster<T>::add(const T& new_item)
{
    auto new_node_ptr = std::make_shared<BinaryNode<T>>(new_item);
    root_ptr_ = placeNode(root_ptr_, new_node_ptr);
}

//Add with vector
template<class T>
void Roster<T>::add(const std::vector<T>& new_items)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < new_items.size(); i++)
    {
        auto new_node_ptr = std::make_shared<BinaryNode<T>>(new_items[i]);
        root_ptr_ = placeNode(root_ptr_, new_node_ptr);
    }
}

//Remove
template<class T>
void Roster<T>::remove(const T& target)
{
    root_ptr_ = removeValue(root_ptr_, target);
}

//Diplay
template<class T>
void Roster<T>::display()
{
    Printer p;
    inorderTraverse(p);
}

template<class T>
void Roster<T>::inorderTraverse(Visitor<T>& visit) const
{
    inorder(visit, root_ptr_);
}

//Helper function
template<class T>
std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> Roster<T>::copyTree(const std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> old_tree_root_ptr) const
{
    std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> new_tree_ptr;

    // Copy tree nodes during preorder tranversal
    if(old_tree_root_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        new_tree_ptr = std::make_shared<BinaryNode<T>>(old_tree_root_ptr->getItem(), nullptr, nullptr);
        new_tree_ptr->setLeftChildPtr(copyTree(old_tree_root_ptr->getLeftChildPtr()));
        new_tree_ptr->setRightChildPtr(copyTree(old_tree_root_ptr->getRightChildPtr()));
    }
    return new_tree_ptr;
}
template<class T>
void Roster<T>::destroyTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr)
{
    if(sub_tree_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        destroyTree(sub_tree_ptr->getLeftChildPtr());
        destroyTree(sub_tree_ptr->getRightChildPtr());
        sub_tree_ptr.reset();
    }
}

template<class T>
int Roster<T>::getHeightHelper(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr) const
{
    if(sub_tree_ptr == nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + std::max(getHeightHelper(sub_tree_ptr->getLeftChildPtr()), getHeightHelper(sub_tree_ptr->getRightChildPtr()));
    }
}

template<class T>
auto Roster<T>::placeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr, std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> new_node_ptr)
{
    if(sub_tree_ptr == nullptr)
    {
        return new_node_ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        if(sub_tree_ptr->getItem() > new_node_ptr->getItem())
        {
            sub_tree_ptr->setLeftChildPtr(placeNode(sub_tree_ptr->getLeftChildPtr(), new_node_ptr));
        }
        else
        {
            sub_tree_ptr->setRightChildPtr(placeNode(sub_tree_ptr->getRightChildPtr(), new_node_ptr));
        }
        return sub_tree_ptr;
    }
}

template<class T>
auto Roster<T>::removeValue(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> sub_tree_ptr, const T target)
{
    if(sub_tree_ptr == nullptr)
    {
        return sub_tree_ptr;
    }
    if(sub_tree_ptr->getItem() == target)
    {
        sub_tree_ptr = removeNode(sub_tree_ptr);
        return sub_tree_ptr;
    }
    else
    {
        if(sub_tree_ptr->getItem() > target)
        {
            sub_tree_ptr->setLeftChildPtr(removeValue(sub_tree_ptr->getLeftChildPtr(), target));
        }
        else
        {
            sub_tree_ptr->setRightChildPtr(removeValue(sub_tree_ptr->getRightChildPtr(), target));
        }
        return sub_tree_ptr;
    }
}

template<class T>
auto Roster<T>::removeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> node_ptr)
{
    //Case 1: Node is a leaf - it is deleted
    if(node_ptr->isLeaf())
    {
        node_ptr.reset();
        return node_ptr;
    }
    //Case 2: Node has one child - parent adopts child
    else if(node_ptr->getLeftChildPtr() == nullptr)
    {
        return node_ptr->getRightChildPtr();
    }
    else if(node_ptr->getRightChildPtr() == nullptr)
    {
        return node_ptr->getLeftChildPtr();
    }
    else
    {
        T new_node_value;
        node_ptr->setRightChildPtr(removeLeftmostNode(node_ptr->getRightChildPtr(), new_node_value));

        node_ptr->setItem(new_node_value);
        return node_ptr;
    }
}

template<class T>
auto Roster<T>::removeLeftmostNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> nodePtr, T& inorderSuccessor)
{
    if(nodePtr->getLeftChildPtr() == nullptr)
    {
        inorderSuccessor = nodePtr->getItem();
        return removeNode(nodePtr);
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr->setLeftChildPtr(removeLeftmostNode(nodePtr->getLeftChildPtr(), inorderSuccessor));
        return nodePtr;
    }
}

template<class T>
void Roster<T>::inorder(Visitor<T>& visit, std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<T>> tree_ptr) const
{
    if(tree_ptr != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(visit, tree_ptr->getLeftChildPtr());
        T the_item = tree_ptr->getItem();
        visit(the_item);
        inorder(visit, tree_ptr->getRightChildPtr());
    }
}

//Operator Overloading for students objects
bool operator <(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    if( a.getLastName() < b.getLastName())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(a.getLastName() == b.getLastName())
    {
        if(a.getFirstName() < b.getFirstName())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool operator >(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    if( a.getLastName() > b.getLastName())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(a.getLastName() == b.getLastName())
    {
        if(a.getFirstName() > b.getFirstName())
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool operator ==(const Student& a, const Student& b)
{
    return (a.getFirstName() == b.getFirstName() && a.getLastName() == b.getLastName());
}
```

Current Roster.hpp:

```
#ifndef ROSTER_HPP
#define ROSTER_HPP

#include "BinaryNode.hpp"
#include "Visitor.hpp"
#include "Student.hpp"
#include "Printer.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Roster
{
public:
    Roster(); // Constructor
    Roster(const Roster& tree); //Copy constructor
    ~Roster(); // Destructor
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int getHeight() const;
    int getNumberOfNodes() const;
    void add(const Student& new_item);
    void add(const std::vector<Student>& new_items);
    void remove(const Student& target);
    void display();
    Student find(const Student& item);
    void clear();

    void inorderTraverse(Visitor<Student>& visit) const;

    Roster& operator= (const Roster& rhs);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> root_ptr_;
    std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> copyTree(const std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> old_tree_root_ptr) const;
    void destroyTree(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> sub_tree_ptr);
    int getHeightHelper(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> sub_tree_ptr) const;
    auto placeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> sub_tree_ptr, std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> new_node_ptr);
    auto removeValue(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> sub_tree_ptr, const Student target);
    auto removeNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> node_ptr);
    auto removeLeftmostNode(std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> nodePtr, Student& inorderSuccessor);
    void inorder(Visitor<Student>& visit, std::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> tree_ptr) const;
    //Operator overloading for students objects
    friend bool operator <(const Student& a, const Student& b);
    friend bool operator >(const Student& a, const Student& b);
    friend bool operator ==(const Student& a, const Student& b);
};

#endif
```

Error:

```
declaration is incompatible with <error-type>
Roster::removeNode(std::__1::shared_ptr<BinaryNode<Student>> node_ptr)
```

Comment: The link [Roster.hpp](https://github.com/HunterCS235Fall2019/project9-devChrisMena/blob/master/Roster.cpp) seems to be dead. Actually, your code looks innocent (so far of what I can see). The only thing which makes me suspicious are the return types `auto`. (That makes the member functions effectively template member functions.) Though, I mistrust `auto` in general although the rest of the world seems to love it... ;-) IMHO, the `auto` return types are good for link issues (like any template which is not implemented in header) but I cannot explain the compile error.

Comment: Please, keep in mind that return type `auto` can be deduced only in the function _definition_ - using the type of the expression after `return`. [C++: “auto” return type deduction](https://oopscenities.net/2018/03/04/auto-return-type-deduction/)

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exact compiler error?

Comment: @Scheff thanks for your comments, I noticed the link is not working since the repo is private, but I will post the code in a minute and error as well!

Comment: Are you aware that `<error-type>` appears before `Roster::removeNode()` just where you have `auto` in code? (I believe, this time my mistrust of `auto` is justified.) One possible fix (IMHO): move the function body into header (to let the compiler correctly deduce what `auto` means). IMHO, my 2nd comment already explains why. (The other possible fix: Don't use `auto` in this case.) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the template case your implementation (.cpp) is a part of the header. In your current implementation - .cpp is not part of the header. Thus your `auto` return types cannot be deduced by compiler whenever someone includes only the header. You ought to declare the return type.